# что означают числа в массиве LogicArrows

Tags: массивы, разработка-игр, криптография, base64

[image: фигура, которую я копировал]

есть такая игра - https://logic-arrows.io в ней можно копировать участки со стрелочками. они сохраняются в буфер обмена в виде строки с шифром base64. расшифровав её в массив я получил такой набор цифр:

```
0,  0, 1,  0, 0,  0, 0,  0,
0, 21, 7,  0, 0, 16, 0, 32,
0,  1, 0, 33, 0,  2, 0, 18,
0, 34, 0
```

это фигура прикреплена выше.
может кто то поможет мне разобраться в этом? заранее спасибо.

Comment: Меняйте стрелочки, смотрите что меняется в массиве. Продолжайте, пока не поймете какая связь.

Comment: я уже понял что 
0,  0, 1,  0, 0,  0, 0,  0,
0, >21<, 7,  0, 0, 16, 0, 32,
0,  1, 0, 33, 0,  2, 0, 18,
0, 34, 0
символ в >таких скобах< отвечает за стрелочку которая используется в фигуре
так же что 0,  0, 1,  0, 0,  0, 0,  0,
0 есть везде, можно сказать начало фигуры или как то так.

и еще не судите строго, я впервые задаю вопрос так что вот.

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался.

```
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 3, 0, 1, 32, 0, 64, 0, 96, 0
~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Я не понял, что это означает.

```
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 3, 0, 1, 32, 0, 64, 0, 96, 0
      ~
```

Это количество чанков, размером 1x15 клеток. Если число стрелок, идущих по горизонтали, превышает 15, они обнуляются. Поэтому это число позволяет программе определить, что клеток по горизонтали больше, чем 15.

```
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 3, 0, 1, 32, 0, 64, 0, 96, 0
                           ~~
```

Это тип стрелки.

```
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 3, 0, 1, 32, 0, 64, 0, 96, 0
                               ~
```

Это количество стрелок минус один.

```
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 3, 0, 1, 32, 0, 64, 0, 96, 0
                                  ~~    ~~     ~~     ~~
```

Это расстояние вверх. Оно указывает, что каждая клетка равна 16 единицам.

```
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 3, 0, 1, 32, 0, 64, 0, 96, 0
                                     ~~     ~~     ~~     ~~
```

Это индикатор поворота стрелки:
0 - вверх
1 - вправо
2 - вниз
3 - влево

Чтобы двигаться по горизонтали, нужно писать 1:1.

```
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0
                                  ~~    ~~    ~~    ~~
```

Это положение по горизонтали. Оно может комбинироваться с вертикалью.

Пока я не изучал смешивание стрелок разных типов, так как мне это не требуется. Возможно, кто-то задаст такой вопрос, и я буду тем, кто на него ответит!